# password less connecting between master and slave node

Tags: ssh

We built a two node cluster with master and slave, we got few issues while trying to connect master node with slave node:

1. We are able to run 'ssh master' in the master node without password
2. While running 'ssh slave' in the master node, we are unable to login without password. Whereas while running ssh `system@slave` its working without password.

Answer (score 1):

You don't say what usernames are involved in these two accounts.  Absent a specific username in the ssh command, ssh assumes that your username is the same on both hosts.  Given that your command works when you specify a username, I'm guessing that the usernames between the two accounts are different.

On master, try this:

```
$ cat << EOF >> ~/.ssh/config
Host slave
  User system

EOF
$ ssh slave
```

If that is not helpful, then please clarify your post to specify your username on master, and your username on slave.

Answer (score 0):

In most cases you need to create ssh key, and put it on from master to slave like.

```sh
# on master
ssh-keygen
# Output truncated
ssh-copy-id root@slave
```

Now you can login without password.

One of best documentation in Linux word comes from Red Hat, so I decided to put here this link: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/system_administrators_guide/s1-ssh-configuration